# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION

Tags: android

[Install APK in Background](http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/how-to-install-a-application-in-background-on-android/#comment-90)

[Git Hub : Source Code](https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-InstallInBackgroundSample)

`google-certificate.keystore` present in certificate folder[See the above git link]

Step 1: I run the code in emulator its works fine [but i need to put that `google-certificate.keystore` location in custom debug keystore[which present in Eclipse -> Windows -> Preference -> Android -> bulit]

Step 2: if i didnt put the location it gives `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

if i connect developer cable and run it to Android device

if i follow step 1 it gives  `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_INSTALL_LOCATION` in console window

if i follow step 2 it installs in device but give same Exception

Edit:

[Signed APK Guide](http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/apk-with-system-privileges/)

here is a step to create as an apk file but i dont where should i enter that command

Edit: Added Manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".InstallInBackgroundSample"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest file. And rephrase your question as it is a bit chaotic.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com i Add my manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog guy himself posts this in the comments:

> Hi guys, I found the problem and unfortunately my news is not good. I discovered that this technique only works for me because I use the security certificate of the simulator (the same certificate used by my device in my case). I researched and saw that there are two ways to use the API hidden:
>   - Put your application pre-installed into a system folder on the ROM
>   - Compile your application using the manufacturer’s security certificate
>   So this will just be useful for you if you will make an application to a specific device and you have the certificate of it, just like me. I apologize for not notifying it before, but I did not know that. I’ll update my post and I’ll warn about it at first. Thank you for the feedback.

What you want is not possible anymore without the phone manufacturers certificate or a rooted device.

Comment: I have rooted device .. what are the steps i need to follow ? where can i find that two certificates

Comment: @Bucks From who ever provided you those rom images.